# using Dagger2 to provide a type with params got error "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method" mean

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

this is the use case where I would like to use dependency injection to inject the infiniteScrollListener, how to write the @Provide InfiniteScrollListener?

```
var infiniteScrollListener: InfiniteScrollListener? = null
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    infiniteScrollListener = InfiniteScrollListener(
            {
                presentor.pullDataFromRemoteServer()
            },
            linearLayout)

    addOnScrollListener(infiniteScrollListener)

    ……
}
```

Edit: maybe the question is how to proivde a type which takes function param (especially in kotlin here), and a param of Android's type of LinearLayoutManager? the LinearLayoutManager would be specific instance which is generated at the fragment's onCreateView().

trying to create a module which could provide a type of InfiniteScrollListener and with params of a function type and a other type.

while build, it got error:

```
    Error [com.example.application.DI.componenet.PresentorComponent.getInfiniteScrollListener()] @javax.inject.Named("func") kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<kotlin.Unit> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Error:[com.example.application.DI.componenet.PresentorComponent.getInfiniteScrollListener()] @javax.inject.Named("layoutManager") android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

not sure what does "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method" mean?

```
@ViewScope
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(PresentorModule::class))
interface PresentorComponent {

    fun inject (fragment: ArtFragment)

    fun getInfiniteScrollListener(): InfiniteScrollListener
}

@Module
class PresentorModule() {

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    fun infiniteScrollListener(func: () -> Unit, layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) : InfiniteScrollListener {
        return InfiniteScrollListener(func, layoutManager)
    }
}


class InfiniteScrollListener (@param:Named("func") val func: () -> Unit,
                          @param:Named("layoutManager") val layoutManager: 
LinearLayoutManager) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    init{}
```

Comment: Dagger can't find `@Named("func") () -> Unit`. You need to add a  `@Provides` annotated method that returns this type. The same applies for your layoutManager.

Comment: thanks for the link. but not sure how to add @Privide to the LinearLayoutManager and the function type param, do you happen to have a sample?

Comment: You already have a `PresentorModule` with one `@Provides` method. You need at least another 2 of those, that return the missing types.

Comment: I am not sure how to @Provide the function type i.e. func: () -> Unit, and the android's LinearLayoutManager which is from android at runtime. sorry still learning the Dagger2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I find a work around for the error, but I dont think it solved the question of how to provide dynamically the handling function for the injected instance. I asked that question in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734281/how-to-provide-different-handling-function-to-the-injected-infinitescrolllistene`